# Summarize Dates

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I want to summarize dates from Monday to Monday but on Saturdays and Sundays accumulate on Friday

```
## A tibble: 10 x 2
#date        value
#<date>      <dbl>
#  1 2020-01-02  1     --- Thurs
#2 2020-01-03 1        --- Fri
#3 2020-01-04  2       --- Sat
#4 2020-01-06  1       --- Mon
#5 2020-01-07  1       --- Tues
#6 2020-01-08 1        --- Wed
#7 2020-01-09  1       --- Thurs
#8 2020-01-10  1       --- Fri
#9 2020-01-11  2       --- Sat
#10 2020-01-13 1       --- Mon
```

This is what i want

```
#date        value
#<date>      <dbl>
#  1 2020-01-02  1     --- Thurs
#2 2020-01-03 3        --- Fri
#4 2020-01-06  1       --- Mon
#5 2020-01-07  1       --- Tues
#6 2020-01-08 1        --- Wed
#7 2020-01-09  1       --- Thurs
#8 2020-01-10  3       --- Fri
#10 2020-01-13 1       --- Mon
```

## Data

```
dd = structure(list(date = structure(c(18263, 18264, 18265, 18267, 18268, 18269, 18270, 18271, 18272, 18274), class = "Date"), value = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `weekdays` to `replace` the 'date' that are on weekends to `NA`, then `fill` the `NA`s with previous non-NA element (assuming the 'date' is already `arrange`d, and then do a `group_by` `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dd %>% 
    mutate(Weekday = weekdays(date),
          date = replace(date, Weekday %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), NA)) %>% 
    fill(date) %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(value = sum(value), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#  date       value
#  <date>     <dbl>
#1 2020-01-02     1
#2 2020-01-03     3
#3 2020-01-06     1
#4 2020-01-07     1
#5 2020-01-08     1
#6 2020-01-09     1
#7 2020-01-10     3
#8 2020-01-13     1
```

Comment: Your code does not work on my computer `> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.2’
> packageVersion("tidyr")
[1] ‘1.1.2’`

Comment: @cdcarrion i have the same versions as you have `packageVersion('dplyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.2’
> packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.1.2’`

Comment: @cdcarrion if you can show the error message, it would be very helpful

Comment: when running your code I have `# A tibble: 10 x 2` and not `# A tibble: 8 x 2`

Comment: @cdcarrion is it on the same 'dd' dataset

Comment: @cdcarrion I tried to run again,  I am getting only 8 x 2.  Please check the output before the `fill` step.  I am assuming that it is the 'weekdays' that would be having an issue.  I used the `base` function

Comment: @cdcarrion Can you show the output of `dd %>% 
    mutate(Weekday = weekdays(date))`

Comment: I get a # A tibble: 10 x 2

Comment: @cdcarrion yes it is  a `mutate` step so it won't change the dimensions, but can you show the values of 'Weekday'

Comment: @cdcarrion you can check these values `dd %>% 
    mutate(Weekday = weekdays(date)) %>% pull(Weekday)
 [1] "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Monday"    "Tuesday"   "Wednesday" "Thursday"  "Friday"    "Saturday"  "Monday"`  If there are no two 'Saturday', that means it is not giving the correct output.  Also, the output of 'weekdays' can be different language based on your settings

Comment: yeap I can show the values. The output is correct and if the language is correct

Comment: your code worked, but in my original database it does not work, I will make another post.

Comment: @cdcarrion the reason would be that the values from 'weekdays' may be in your language and not on English.  In that case, you have to change the `Weekday %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday")` with the corresponding values for 'Saturday' and 'Sunday'